# How to use Google Cloud Storage as a storage layer of Delta Lake?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, delta-lake

Can I use Google Cloud Storage as a storage layer of Delta Lake?

---

Found on [slack](https://delta-users.slack.com/archives/CJ70UCSHM/p1577972403071000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible in Delta Lake up to and including 0.5.0.

There's an issue to track this at https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/294. Feel free to upvote that to help get it prioritized.

---

Just a day after Google posted [Getting started with new table formats on Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/getting-started-with-new-table-formats-on-dataproc):

> We’re announcing that table format projects Delta Lake and Apache Iceberg (Incubating) are now available in the latest version of Cloud Dataproc (version 1.5 Preview). You can start using them today with either Spark or Presto. Apache Hudi is also available on Dataproc 1.3.

Comment: if BigQuery is used as the service channel for BI/Reporting/Analytics there's noway to integrate DeltaLake tables with Bigquery right ?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya Have you seen [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example)?

Comment: this connector is for Reading/Writing BigQuery data from a Spark app. But my requirement is different.Lets say we use delta-lake format to create Delta,Bronze and Gold layer ( https://live-delta-io.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Delta-Lake-marketecture-0423c.png ). Then the result datasets in the Gold layer needs to be served through BigQuery, its not possible since BQ cant read DeltaLake files

Comment: Why not to load this gold Delta table and save it to BigQuery?

Comment: yeah, thats a possibility. but that adds an extra "loading" layer between Gold Layer and serving-layer ? If I use Presto/StarBurst as the serving-layer instead, this extra "loading" layer is not required. Well.. since BQ is a proprietary tech, guess we cant expect the "DeltaLake" format support ,to load them as external tables in BQ.

Comment: actually I was thinking about loading into BigQuery. From DeltaLake, we need to reload the entire table into BigQuery every time ? This is not performant. Ideally it should be able to only apply the differences to BigQuery table.

Comment: That's doable but not available out of the box (= requires some coding). Hint: use transaction log of a delta table to know the changes (actions).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.
Here's a sample code and the libraries that you need:

Make sure to set first your credential, you can either part of the code or as environment:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={gcs-key-path.json}
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException
import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions
import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.DatasetInfo

spark.conf.set("parentProject", {Proj})
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")   
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark.conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
spark.conf.set("spark.delta.logStore.gs.impl", "io.delta.storage.GCSLogStore")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")


val targetTablePath = "gs://{bucket}/{dataset}/{tablename}"
spark.range(5, 10).write.format("delta")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(targetTablePath)
```

Libraries that you need:

```
"io.delta" % "delta-core_2.12" % "1.0.0",
"io.delta" % "delta-contribs_2.12" % "1.0.0",
"com.google.cloud.spark" % "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12" % "0.21.1",
"com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "1.9.4-hadoop3"
```

Checking my delta files in GCS:

```
$ gsutil ls gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/part-00000-ce79bfc7-e28f-4929-955c-56a7a08caf9f-c000.snappy.parquet
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/part-00001-dda0bd2d-a081-4444-8983-ac8f3a2ffe9d-c000.snappy.parquet
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/part-00002-93f7429b-777a-42f4-b2dd-adc9a482a6e8-c000.snappy.parquet
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/part-00003-e9874baf-6c0b-46de-891e-032ac8b67287-c000.snappy.parquet
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/part-00004-ede54816-2da1-412f-a9e3-5233e77258fb-c000.snappy.parquet
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/_delta_log/
gs://r-dps-datapipeline-dev/testoliver/oliver_sample_delta3/_symlink_format_manifest/
```